Oauth2 outbound email smtp settings
on civicrm 4.53 installed in wordpress, i've setup oauth2 plugin to outbound SMTP emails through oauth2 authentication via exchange online server.
Meanwhile under civi -> system settings -> smtp configuration what configuration settings do i need to change for use of oauth2 civicrm plugin ?

Current settings send emails through ms direct-send option.

Thank you

Only inbound/bounce retrieval works with oauth. There is currently no outbound support.
